# I need to compare 2 work sheets and update one worksheet with the info from another

Tags: vba, excel

I've been trying to compare 2 sheets and update one of the sheets with some info.  I know about vlookup but I don't understand how it works.

Here is what I need to do:

1. Sheets("Product") has many products on the A column (over 8,000)

   - I need to select all products 1 by 1 and try to find if there is an EXACT MATCH (LookAt:=xlWhole) on the Sheets("Parker List").
2. If there is a match on the Sheets("Parker List") I need to take SOME of the values of the Sheets("Parker List") and put them into Sheets("Product")
3. If there is no match, I need to go to the next number in line in sheets("Product")

The values switch are:
From Sheets("Parker List") I need "B" and "S" and than put the infos in respectively "F" and "H" of the sheets("Product") ONLY if the products of sheets("Product") are found in Sheets("Parker List").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If for example the product name is in column A in both sheets, you could use something like this in column F of Sheets("Product") to get the appropiate value from column B of Sheets("Parker List") :

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,'Parker List'!A:A,0)),"",INDEX('Parker List'!B:B,MATCH(A1,'Parker List'!A:A,0)))
```

The key to this is to use 0 as the third optional argument of the MATCH function which will return an error value when a match is not made. ISERROR will detect this error and the IF function will perform the required calculations accordingly.

Comment: If there is no match in Sheets("Parker List") then I need to continue on the next line on Sheets("Product")

Comment: What do you mean that you need to continue on the next line? Do you mean that you take the values according to the product name on the next line?

Comment: I need to search value of my sheet and find the same value on the other sheet.  IF there is no EXACT MATCH on the 2nd sheet, than noting has to be updated.  If there is an EXACT MATCH, than I need to take the value of B and S of the 2nd sheet and put in respectively in the F and H column of the 1st sheet

Comment: Are there a pre-existing values in columns F and H that you wouldn't want to lose if there is no exact match? or is it blank?

Comment: It's blank... basically I need to fill F and H only if there is an EXACT match on A on both sheets but... A6048 could match with A10385 on the other sheet

Comment: I've edited the formula so that it will leave a blank value if there is no exact match. Give this a try and see if it works for you.

Comment: Wierd... it's just pasting the text and not using the fomula =X

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73785/discussion-between-konsume-and-guy-hodges).

Comment: Ok, I got it to work but It's just leaving everything "blank" =X